# Does this site have private messages?

Tags: discussion

So I'm sorry if this isn't the right place to ask but, is it possible for us to follow someone here on Stack exchange and send messages and engage? Is there any button on somebody's profile where you just press the button and you start following that person? If so, how to follow someone to communicate with them privately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have chat for that (https://chat.stackexchange.com), with a room for the Linguistics site in particular. You can go in there and ping someone. But generally speaking, the only way to contact a specific person is to interact with their content (e.g. commenting on their questions).

Comment: Alright thanks!

Comment: Chat has a few caveats, namely that it's not private and you can't actually ping anyone unless they're active in that room—you can leave a message but they probably won't see it. (There are only exceptions to this for moderators.)